# Remove HTML extension tag in a URL with .htaccess without renaming each <A> link in HTML file

Tags: html, .htaccess

This piece of code in the .htaccess file does function but only if I rename each A HREF link without the .html extension.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Is there a different approach that would not required to rename each link in each html file?

Thanks!

Comment: That is possible by using a content filter, but it is extremely inefficient. Instead you indeed should revise your files if you are using static html files. You do not have to do that manually one by one. You can use a utility for that where you can define a search expression and a replacement pattern, which converts all files you throw at it.

Comment: If you don't change the `<A>` link in the HTML source, then you aren't actually removing the HTML extension and it's still visible for anyone (including search engines) to see.

Comment: You <a> with .html should work as it will not be rewritten by your code.

Comment: Use a  `filename.html` to `/filename` redirect  in your htaccess.

Comment: @AmitVerma No, that is not what is asked here.